# Find, analytically, the value of the following limit.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, summation, telescopic-series

How would one prove that$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k}+\sqrt{2k-1}}$$ converges (rather slowly) to $\frac {1}{\sqrt{2}}$, which appears obvious from numerical computation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k}+\sqrt{2k-1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2\left(\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k-\frac{1}{2}}\right)}<\frac{1}{\sqrt2\left(\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k-1}\right)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\left(\sqrt{k}-\sqrt{k-1}\right),$$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k}+\sqrt{2k-1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2\left(\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k-\frac{1}{2}}\right)}>\frac{1}{\sqrt2\left(\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}\right)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\left(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}\right)$$ and use the telescoping summation.

Comment: It doesn't telescope.  You always add roots of even numbers and subtract roots of odd numbers.

Comment: yes, that seems to be it, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome! @saulspatz Thank you very much! I fixed.

Comment: You are most welcome.  Nice answer.  I was getting nowhere with integrals.

Comment: @saulspatz, if you are interested I got *somewhere* with integrals ;)

Comment: @YuriyS Thanks, but I think this solution is a lot cleaner than using integrals.

Comment: @saulspatz, yes, of course it is, but the more the merrier

Comment: @YuriyS I'm sorry, I didn't realize you had posted an answer.  Of course, I'll be glad to read it.

Comment: @saulspatz Is there a standard way of doing sums with integrals? Do you try to manipulate it into a Riemann sum somehow, or are there other ways? Thanks.

Comment: @YuriyS Is there a standard way of doing sums with integrals? Do you try to manipulate it into a Riemann sum somehow, or are there other ways? Thanks.

Comment: No there isn't a standard way to do sums with integrals, but integrals are usually easier to compute than sums, so one tries to find integrals that will bound the sum from above and below.  With skill and luck, one may find bounds that converge to the same value in the limit, thus allowing  one to compute the limit of the sum.

Answer (score 2):

Well, we can write the sum under limit as $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{k}{n}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{k}{n}-\dfrac{1}{2n}}\right)}$$ which is a Riemann sum for $f(x) = 1/(2\sqrt{2x})$ over $[0,1]$ with partition points $x_k=k/n$ and suitable tag points $t_k$. The desired limit is $2^{-1/2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{2\sqrt{x}}=1/\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: What an elegant proof

Answer (score 0):

**Another interesting way to prove the lower bound.**

Consider:

$$A=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k}+\sqrt{2k-1}}$$

$$I_k=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k}+\sqrt{2k-1}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^\infty e^{-(4k-1)x^2} e^{-4k x^2 \sqrt{1-1/(2k)}} dx$$

Since $(\sqrt{2k}+\sqrt{2k-1})^2=4 k-1+4 \sqrt{k(k-1/2)}$.

$$\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{2k}}= 1-\frac{1}{4k}-\frac{1}{32k^2}-O \left( \frac{1}{8k^3} \right)<1-\frac{1}{4k}$$

We have:

$$I_k > \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^\infty e^{-8kx^2} dx$$

$$A \geq \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^n  \int_0^\infty e^{-8kx^2} dx= \\ =\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-8 x^2}-e^{-8(n+1) x^2}}{1-e^{-8 x^2}}  dx$$

$$A \geq \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n} \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-8 y^2/n}-e^{-8(1+1/n) y^2}}{1-e^{-8 y^2/n}}  dy$$

$$A \geq \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n} \int_0^\infty \frac{1-e^{-8 y^2}}{e^{8 y^2/n}-1}  dy=\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^\infty \frac{1-e^{-8 y^2}}{y^2}  dy$$

> $$A \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\int_0^\infty \frac{1-e^{-z^2}}{z^2}  dz= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

The last integral is easy to prove using integration by parts.